# php - export string with both double quotes and comma into csv format

Tags: php, csv

I know how to handle string with comma into csv, and string with double quote into csv,

but if a string with both comma and double quote, how to convert it ?

like:

> Seminar on "Changing Myanmar: Institutions, Personalities and Expectations" 10 Feb 2012;

by default I added " " to the string, so it can convert to csv file with comma,

but if this string also contains "", then the field separate into two fields in csv.

I tried this:

> "Seminar on """Changing Myanmar: Institutions, Personalities and Expectations""" 10 Feb 2012"

but it is wrong...

Comment: Your data is ambiguous.  You won't be able to reliably decode from it without some knowledge about the fields.  If you can re-export your file, use an escape character, such as a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) is the best way to avoid any problem.

Comment: This un-implemented hint could have been a comment under the question instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<?php
@unlink( 'test.csv' );
$fp = fopen( 'test.csv', 'w' );

$text = '"Changing Myanmar: Institutions, Personalities and Expectations"';

fwrite( $fp, '"'. str_replace( '"', '""', $text ) . '", "test"' . "\n" );

fclose( $fp );
?>
```

**Reading from this csv file:**

```
$fp = fopen( 'test.csv', 'r' );

while( ( $data = fgetcsv( $fp, '', ',' ) ) !== false ) {
    echo $data[0];
}

fclose( $fp );
```

**Output -** `"Changing Myanmar: Institutions, Personalities and Expectations"`

Hope this helps.